# How to pass as variable into .xslt 1.0 key expressions

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Following on from my original question:
[Filtering, Grouping, Counting and Selecting specific nodes in XML using XSLT 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39275466/filtering-grouping-counting-and-selecting-specific-nodes-in-xml-using-xslt-1-0)

I've now run into another problem. Using this code that was kindly provided by michael.hor257k

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="vehicle-by-series" match="Vehicle[Model='KA']" use="Series" />

<xsl:template match="/Dealer">
    <xsl:for-each select="Vehicle[Model='KA'][count(. | key('vehicle-by-series', Series)[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="Model"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Series"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="grp" select="key('vehicle-by-series', Series)" />
        <xsl:value-of select="count($grp)"/>
        <xsl:text> in stock, starting from </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$grp">
            <xsl:sort select="Price" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm passing in the parameter model:

```
<xsl:param name="model" />
```

From an asp.NET URL variable. 
I want to substitute the currently hardcoded KA for the model parameter. From the searching I've done you can't use parameters or variables in a key expression in XSLT 1.0. And I don't have the option to upgrade to 2.0. Mores the pity.

Would really appreciate some more help please.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:param name="model"/>

<xsl:key name="vehicle-by-series" match="Vehicle" use="concat(Model, '|', Series)" />

<xsl:template match="/Dealer">
    <xsl:for-each select="Vehicle[Model=$model][count(. | key('vehicle-by-series', concat(Model, '|', Series))[1]) = 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="Model"/>
        <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="Series"/>
        <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
        <xsl:variable name="grp" select="key('vehicle-by-series', concat(Model, '|', Series))" />
        <xsl:value-of select="count($grp)"/>
        <xsl:text> in stock, starting from </xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$grp">
            <xsl:sort select="Price" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <xsl:value-of select="Price"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That looked promising, but unfortunately seems to be pulling all the models now.

Comment: @Strontium_99 I was testing the other suggestion and inadvertently pasted that here. Try it now.

Comment: You, Sir, are a legend. Thanks once again for your help.